# OpenCV 2.4.7 GPL Licensing Issue with mser.cpp

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using openCV 2.4.7 with C++ to build an application which will eventually be distributed. As far as I understand, openCV falls under the BSD open source license.

However, I found that there is a package called features2d which has a class called MSER which uses a table called "chitab3". This table is extracted from a paper which is under GPL. This is present in the source code of modules/features2d/src/mser.cpp as follows:

> - The color image algorithm is taken from: Maximally Stable Colour Regions for Recognition and Match;
> - it should be much slower than grey image method ( 3~4 times );
> - the chi_table.h file is taken directly from paper's source code which is distributed under GPL.

Since the MSER class is available in features2d, when features2d.dll is distributed so is MSER and eventually chitab3 as well.

All this led to the following questions:

1. What would be the best practice to prevent the usage of chitab3? I have no use for the MSER class but need the features2d.dll as it has other modules required for the application.
2. If chitab3 is under GPL, even MSER, features2d and openCV should be under GPL. Why is openCV under BSD although one of it's modules is under GPL?

Comment: Without seeing the actual table data, it's hard to judge if it's copyrightable at all. The GPL works within copyright, and cannot protect what's outside copyright. E.g. a cosine table definitely is not copyrightable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should report this issue directly to the [OpenCV team](http://opencv.org) to make them aware of it.

For your application, you can simply **recompile** OpenCV from the sources after moving MSER to the **non-free** OpenCV module, and explicitly disabling the non-free module in the build system. Then, the dll that you ship does not contain any data/code that cannot be used at your own convenience.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've contacted the OpenCV team through the Q and A forums. I'm waiting for their suggestion as well.